# Groupby and sum several columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I am trying to groupby several columns. With one column it is easy, just `df.groupby('c1').['c3].sum()`

Original dataframe

```
c1    c2    c3
1     1    2
1     2    12
2     1    87
2     2    12
2     3    87
2     3    13
```

Desired result

```
c2   c3(c1_1)    c3(c1_2)
1    2           87
2    12          12
3    (0?)        100
```

Where c3(c1_1) means sum of column c3 where c1 has a value of 1

I have no idea how to apply groupby on this. It would be nice, if someone will show not only how to solve it, but what to read to have no such stupid questions

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but it is unclear. Why have the column names changed and what is the expected output? Is that a NaN value in `c3(c1_1)`?

Comment: What does the underscore represent? I'm sorta half seeing the pattern

Comment: @roganjosh thank you for the comment. I added some description now.

Comment: @kiyac please mention your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by multiple columns at once by providing a list to `groupby`. If you don't mind the output being formatted slightly differently, you can achieve this result through

```
In [32]: df.groupby(['c2', 'c1']).c3.sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[32]:
c1   1    2
c2
1    2   87
2   12   12
3    0  100
```

With a bit of work, this can be massaged into the form you give as well.